# What percent of the US Federal Budget was spent on WW2?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, economy, government

From 1941 Dec 7 to 1945 May 8, what percent of the US Federal Budget was spent on the war? I would like to compare this to today's military spending, which according to [this paragraph in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_budget_of_the_United_States#Military_budget_and_total_US_federal_spending), is 28 - 38%.

Comment: Is wartime spending actually included in regular budgets?

Comment: I doubt that any analysis could be complete without a nuanced analysis of deficit spending.

Comment: The wiki article you link for 'today's' spending opens discussing fiscal year **2010**. The chart to the right has a Title which says **Fiscal year 2015**, and the caption for the same chart reads **Fiscal Year 2012**. You might want to look for a better figure to *start* from for your comparison.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [chart](https://www.usgovernmentspending.com/spending_chart_1900_2020USp_XXs2li111mcn_30f_20th_Century_Defense_Spending) shows that the percentage of U.S. GDP spent on defense rose from low single digits in 1940, to nearly 40% during the war years, before dropping below 10%, even today.

A [related chart](https://www.usgovernmentspending.com/spending_chart_1900_2020USf_18s2li011mcn_30f_20th_Century_Defense_Spending) shows that the percentage of the federal budget spent during the WWII years on defense, was as high as about 80% falling to about 30% today.

Comment: That's GDP, not budget.

Comment: [*This*](https://www.usgovernmentspending.com/spending_chart_1900_2020USf_18s2li011mcn_30f_20th_Century_Defense_Spending) chart is defense spending as a percentage of federal budget. (I believe this is *federal* defense spending as a percentage of federal budget, but the site isn't entirely clear.)

Comment: @user2357112: Added the second chart. Thanks for your help.